# How to find area of triangle using normal vector?

Tags: vectors

I am trying to figure out the area of the triangle in the image provided.

[image: Triangle]

I understood why they took the magnitude of the normal vector as it gives the length of the height of the triangle. However, what I do not understand is why they only multiplied it by 1/2 instead of multiplying by the length of V and then times 1/2 (base*height*.5)? Any help I would appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: The magnitude of the cross product of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ is the area of the parallellogram spanned by these vectors; the triangle has half the  area.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this works is because the magnitude of the cross product of any two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $|a||b|\sin\theta$. Of course, the direction is along a unit vector that's normal to both those vectors, but that's irrelevant here. What matters is the magnitude.

The area of a plane triangle with two sides $a$ and $b$ is $\frac 12 ab \sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between those sides. Showing this is easy: if $a$ is taken as the base, the height is $b\sin\theta$ whereas if $b$ is taken as the base, the height is $a \sin\theta$.

I hope the relationship becomes obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the modulus of the cross product of two vectors gives you the area of the parallelogram spanned by those two vectors. So divide that by 2 to find the area of the corresponding triangle.